# ImageJ: .show() does not show an image

Tags: javascript, imagej

I very new to javascript and I would like to process some images in Fiji. I have been using the macro language for a while, but I am trying to get familiar with the formal ImageJ/Fiji API. I am trying to run the folowing simplistic piece of code, it runs with no errors but it does not show any image in the end. What's going wrong?

```
importClass(Packages.ij.plugin.filter.GaussianBlur);


var image = IJ.openImage("/home/.../KNIIC_BC_Cam2_AirBubble2_Image1038.bmp");
IJ.run(image, "8-bit", "");

var dpl = image.getProcessor().duplicate();
var gs = new GaussianBlur();
gs.blur(dpl,20);
new ImagePlus(gs).show();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this related to http://fiji.sc/Javascript_Scripting#Creating_a_script_for_ImageJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way how you deal with the `ImagePlus`: in the last line, you try to create a `new ImagePlus`, but there is no chance that this contains any information of your loaded image.

`GaussianBlur` processes an `ImageProcessor` that you'll get via the `ImagePlus#getProcessor()` method. If you look at the [API documentation](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/plugin/filter/GaussianBlur.html), you'll also see that `blur(ImageProcessor,double)` is deprecated in favor of one of the other methods: you might want to use `blurGaussian(ImageProcessor, double, double, double)`here.

This code would work:

```
importClass(Packages.ij.plugin.filter.GaussianBlur);

var imp = IJ.openImage("http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/images/clown.jpg");
IJ.run(imp, "8-bit", "");

var ip = imp.getProcessor();
var gs = new GaussianBlur();
gs.blurGaussian(ip,20,20,0.01);
imp.show();
```

however it uses the low level way of interfering with the `GaussianBlur` class. To make your life easy, you can also record the javascript command in the GUI via *Plugins > Macros > Record...* and then choosing *Record: Javascript* before performing the Gaussian blur via *Process > Filters > Gaussian Blur...*. This would make your code much shorter:

```
var imp = IJ.openImage("http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/images/clown.jpg");
IJ.run(imp, "8-bit", "");
IJ.run(imp, "Gaussian Blur...", "sigma=20");

imp.show();
```

For general help with Javascript scripting in ImageJ, see [these](http://fiji.sc/Javascript_Scripting) [two](http://fiji.sc/Scripting_toolbox) links to the Fiji wiki.

**Edit**: Starting from [ImageJ 1.47n5](http://fiji.sc/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=imagej.git;a=commitdiff;h=bb0ffe96940de0c8ca39928acbad636dcd4daf29#patch9), `ImageProcessor` has a new method `blurGaussian(double sigma)`, shortening the above (low level) code to:

```
var imp = IJ.openImage("http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/images/clown.jpg");
IJ.run(imp, "8-bit", "");
imp.getProcessor().blurGaussian(20);
imp.show();
```

Comment: Thank you Jan! Your reply was very helpful and enlightening! I was aware of the "easy" way to do it, but in the future I will need to compute custom stuff that are not available through the menus and thus on recordable.

Comment: I just edited my answer to account for the recent addition of `ImageProcessor.blurGaussian(double)` in ImageJ v1.47n